# What should I do If I can't flag as duplicate because answer is neither accepted nor upvoted?

Tags: discussion

I answered this question: [CGI-Bin does not seem to be set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499943/cgi-bin-does-not-seem-to-be-set-up/500281#500281) and today I found this question: [how to set up cgi-bin directories for virtual host set up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545938/how-to-set-up-cgi-bin-directories-for-virtual-host-set-up#comment748031_545938)

I suggested to use that answer and OP said that it work.

Now I tried to flag as duplicate, but I can't, because that answer is neither accepted nor upvoted.

So I wonder what I should do. Should I answer this new question, hope that this new answer is accepted and than flag the old one as duplicate?

Comment: Thanks to those who upvoted, I was able to flag as duplicate the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as you've done.

- Leave a comment on the new question pointing at your older answer,
- Draw attention to the new question: here in Meta, in our Chat room or even with actual moderator flags,
- If people agree, you'll get a couple of votes and the new question will be closed off.